# Can't send ASCII from arduino uno to magnet sensor by RS232 serial

Tags: arduino, serial-port

im trying to send ASCII code "?MGT \r"(CR) from arduino to magnet sensor, but it doesn't work.
What is the problem with my code?

CODE:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#define Rx 6
#define Tx 7
SoftwareSerial mySerial(Rx, Tx);

String MGT = "?MGT ";

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
    Serial.begin(115200); 
    mySerial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println("----------START------------");
    mySerial.listen();
    mySerial.println(MGT);
    delay(1000);
}

void loop() {
//Check the normal Serial from serial monitor
    if (Serial.available()) {
        String send_com = Serial.readStringUntil(';');
        Serial.println(send_com);
        mySerial.println(send_com);
        int get_ccom = mySerial.read();
        Serial.println(get_ccom);
        Serial.setTimeout(1000);
        delay(10);
    } else {
        Serial.print("aa! ");
        delay(1000);
    }
//Check the software Serial signal
    if (mySerial.available()) {
        String get_com = mySerial.readString();
        Serial.print("available");
        Serial.println(get_com);
        Serial.setTimeout(1000);
    }else{
        Serial.println("bb!");
    }
}
```

Serial monitor result:

----------START------------
09:30:10.880 -> aa! bb!
09:30:11.864 -> aa! bb!
09:30:12.882 -> aa! bb!
09:30:13.864 -> aa! bb!
09:30:14.882 -> aa! bb!
09:30:15.867 -> aa! bb!

Comment: `.println()` will also send an `'\n'` following `'\r'`.  Is that a problem for you or not?

Comment: should i send that command by Serial.write()? I tried but nothing change.